# Logic behind word-boundary difference between BSD grep and GNU grep

Tags: grep, gnu, bsd

Can someone please explain/help me understand the logic behind this difference between BSD grep and GNU grep? I've added carets below the matches.

```
$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
$ cat t1 
admin:*:80:root
$ grep '\<.' t1
admin:*:80:root
^^^^^   ^^ ^^^^
```

versus

```
$ grep --version
GNU grep 2.6.3

Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ cat t1 
admin:*:80:root
$ grep '\<.' t1
admin:*:80:root
^       ^  ^
```

It seems GNU grep is getting it right and BSD grep isn't. I thought `\<` is supposed to get the word boundary? Note `grep '\<ad' t1` seems to get the same result in both versions, e.g.:

```
$ cat t2
admin:*:80:root
sadmin:*:81:root
$ grep '\<ad' t2
admin:*:80:root
^^
```

What gives?

Thanks in advance.

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\>` to specify word boundary wouldn't work for `BSD grep`.  Try `[[:<:]]` instead.

[This post](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-userlevel/2012/12/02/msg006954.html) gives pretty useful information on word boundaries for various utilities.

Comment: "It's long been a pet peeve of mine that regexp matching for word
boundaries has an annoying dependency on the implementation."

For real.